# How to limit bullet fire

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code. It is a program that fires bullets until there aren't any left.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
import random                        

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color, size, x, y, xspeed, yspeed):
        self.canvas = canvas 
        self.color = color 
        self.size = size 
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y 
        self.xspeed = xspeed 
        self.yspeed = yspeed
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(x,y,x+size,y+size,fill=color)

    def move(self): 
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        (x1, y1, x2, y2)=self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        (self.x, self.y)=(x1, y1)
        if x1<=0 or x2>=WIDTH:         
            self.xspeed=-self.xspeed
        if y1<=0 or y2>=HEIGHT:
            self.yspeed=-self.yspeed

WIDTH=800
HEIGHT=400
bullets=[]

def fire(event):
    bullets.append(Ball(canvas, 10, "red", 100, 200, 10, 0))

window = Tk()  
canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", fire)


spaceship = Ball(canvas, "green", 100, 100, 200, 0, 0)
enemy = Ball(canvas, "red", 100, 500, 200, 0, 5) 

while True:
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.move()
        if (bullet.x+bullet.size) >= WIDTH:
            canvas.delete(bullet.id)
            bullets.remove(bullet)
            if (bullet_count<9):
                bullet_count+=1
            else:
                id=canvas.create_text(100,50, fill="red",font="Times 30 italic 
                     bold",text="Hello World")
                break

    enemy.move()
    window.update()
    sleep(0.03)
```

I just want to fire 10 bullets and if there are no remaining bullets, I want to create a message box like `id = canvas.create_text(100, 50, fill="red",font="Times 30 italic bold",text="Out of bullets")`.

How can I accomplish this goal? I am not particularly experienced at Python.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the number of bullets fired inside `fire()`, not in the while loop.

Also better not use while loop in a tkinter application, use `.after()` instead.

```
bullet_count = 10

def fire(event):
    global bullet_count
    if bullet_count > 0:
        bullets.append(Ball(canvas, "red", 10, 100, 200, 10, 0))
        bullet_count -= 1
    else:
        # show out of bullets
        canvas.itemconfig(message, text="Out of bullets")

...

# text object to show the "Out of Bullets" message
message = canvas.create_text(100, 50, anchor="nw", fill="red", font="Times 30 italic bold")

# function to replace the while loop
def move_bullets():
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.move()
        if bullet.x+bullet.size >= WIDTH:
            canvas.delete(bullet.id)
            bullets.remove(bullet)
    enemy.move()
    window.after(30, move_bullets)

move_bullets()  # start the bullets animation
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Plese provide more context. But here is a hint

```
for bullet in bullets[:10]:
    # we try to fire 10 bullets
    # if we have less bullets we fire them
    # but we have more, here we only fire 10 of them
    bullet.move()
    if (bullet.x+bullet.size) >= WIDTH:
        canvas.delete(bullet.id)
        bullets.remove(bullet)

# If we had less bullets and we fired less than 10 bullets
if len(bullets) <= 0:
    id = canvas.create_text(100, 50, fill="red", font="Times 30 italicbold",text="you have less than 10 bullets")
```